# Access 2013 primary key in where condition of macro builder

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I've searched the web and this site but have not seen an answer to my particular question. I want to produce a report based on the current record (easy), but with the primary key as the Where Condition (not so easy). I'm hoping to use the macro builder and avoid VBA, if possible.

In the macro builder, I can easily get this done by inputting "`[First Name]=[Reports]![Contracts]![First Name]`" in the Where Condition. '`First Name`' is just a regular field present in both my main table and the report. However, customer names can change easily so I'm hoping I can use the primary key "`Id`", as that should be a more reliable and unchanging value. But if I try with "`[Id]=[Reports]![Contracts]![Id]`", I get the whole 'Enter a Parameter' dialog (and even if I input the Id value, it just outputs every record).

Why does this work with the First Name field but not the Id field? Is it because Access doesn't like to use primary keys for the Where Condition? If I use the expression builder, Access will recognize the Id field as present in my report and (therefore, I would think) as usable for this purpose. I'm assuming I'm missing something on the left of the equal sign? I've tried with Me. and Me! before and inside the brackets, but nothing. I've also tried stuff like "`[Tables]![Main]![Id]=[Reports]![Contracts]![Id]`" and "`[Main]![Id]=[Reports]![Contracts]![Id]`".

Comment: Please disregard, it was a dumb mistake of not including the Id field in my Details report. I don't think there's a difference between using a primary key or using a regular field, I was just making a fundamental error. No wonder someone immediately gave me a -1 as soon as I posted lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating a temporary variable and pass that to the open report action.

For example, let's say you want to open a report for a record when the user clicks on the field 'First Name' for that record in datasheet view. Your On Click embedded macro would be:

```
SetTempVar
    Name tmpID
    Expression = [Id]
OpenReport
    Report Name Contracts
    View Report
    Filter Name
    Where Condition = [Id]=[TempVars]![tmpID]
    Window Mode Dialog
RemoveTempVar
    Name tmpID
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, although still nothing. Your code takes my general list of contracts (a report) and basically deletes all other records from view, probably because you wanted me to try with `Report Name: Contracts`. However, I should've clarified I want this macro to run off a button on the Contracts report to open up the Details report. If I change it to `Report Name: Details`, I start getting the Enter Parameter Value dialog again. But your idea was good because apparently Access is now able to reference the Id field as a filtering criterion.

Comment: Wow I'm a dumbass, disregard everything. I had not included the Id field in the Details report. It worked with First Name because the Details report included First Name.

Turns out you don't need to do anything special for primary keys, my Where Condition is simply `[Id]=[Reports]![Contracts]![Id]`. Thanks for your help.